# c# separate context menu for listview header

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, contextmenu

How do i assign a separate context menu to the column headers of a listview in c#?

Answer (score 2):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView) has an ColumnRightClick event. The demo shows how to show a menu in response to that event.